# sending/receiving external email without a domain name?

Tags: sendmail, postfix-mta, mail-server, hmail-server

I want to install a mail server to send email and receive external email (from other server from the internet) either with sendmail or postfix in unix or hMailserver on windows. Since it's easy to setup a web server that people can access over the internet without the need of a domain name, and that works pretty much like any other web server that use a domain name. I was wondering if it is possible to setup a mail server that could also work, with IP only just like any mail server on the internet works.

email addresses would be like:

> example@my.ip.is.here

If it's not possible will it be possible to do so with a domain name of type A (my IP is linked to an A type domain name)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can`t sending mails from your ip adress :D
Hook even free domain to you server, or like you write put your A domain to mailserver.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `example@[my.ip.is.here]` addresses.  Sendmail supports it but you will pretty soon hit spam filters or mail server without support of such addresses. Try Kacper's suggestion.